# Hide vue router from a starting page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to hide vue-router from my starting page.

```
localhost:8080/lp/ <-- hide
localhost:8080/lp/#/page1 <-- show
```

I tried with the simple method and v-if which returns true or false depending on the current route. Unfortunately, the other pages have the same '/LP/' path so they stay also hidden.

```
<a class="list-group-item" v-link="{ path: '/' }" v-if="!isHomePage()">Home</a>

isHomePage: function() {
  return this.$route.path === '/lp'
}
```

Comment: You can try adding a redirect to that route, so that when route is clicked , yoi are redirected to another ppath. More here ( https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$route.path()` returns only the resolved absolute path, so: `localhost:8080/lp/` and `localhost:8080/lp/#/page1`, will be both return as `/lp/`.

It looks like `$route.fullPath()` is what you need. `fullPath()` will return the resolved URL as well as the query and hash. So if you really are on the home page (`/lp` and not `/lp/#/page1`) it will only return `/lp`.

You could do something like:

```
<a class="list-group-item" v-link="{ path: '/' }" v-if="$route.fullPath !== '/lp'">Home</a>
```